# parsing a css file with sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Tags: php, css, parsing

I use this class to parse a .css file.
https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser
I thought it's easy but this class is complicated and I'm completly green in object oriented programing, so I have a problem.

(...) including all class files etc.

```
$oParser = new CSSParser(file_get_contents('files/sample.css'));
$oDoc = $oParser->parse();
$selectors=$oDoc->getAllRuleSets();
$nazwy=$oDoc->getContents();

foreach($selectors as $selektor=> $val)
    {       
    $w=$val->getSelectors();            
    echo "<h3>$selektor</h3>";
    $tmp=$val->getRules();

        foreach($tmp as $nazwa => $attrib)
        {
        $wartosc= $attrib->getValue();
        echo "<br>$nazwa:$wartosc;";            
        }               
    }
```

this code will output something like this

```
<h1>0</h1>
color:red;
margin:10px;


<h1>1</h1>
color:green;
margin:20px;
```

it's almost ok but I want selectors names (eg div #someid) instead of index of current css block.Have any idea how to get those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo "<h3>".implode(', ' $w)."</h3>"`.

The reason is as follows: `$val` represents a declaration block which is a rule set with several comma-separated selectors (The key `$selektor` only contains the index of the declaration block which is completely arbitrary for most usages). To get the selectors, use `$val->getSelectors()` (which you did). This will get you an array of all selectors.

The declaration block:

```
h1, h2 { value: 1; }
```

will thus be parsed into a `CSSDeclarationBlock` object with the selector array ['h1', 'h2']. To get back the selectors as they were originally defined, use `implode`.

Comment: You’re welcome. I only found this because I have a Google Search Alert for „sabberworm“…